# running python script unbuffered on boot?

Tags: python, logging, background, raspberry-pi

I have a script that runs in the background, and it is supposed to run 24/7, but some times it crashes.  But it's running on my headless pi, so I don't get to see the error messages when it crashes.
I found a solution where I can have the script print to a file "unbuffered"

```
python -u my_background_script.py > errorfile.txt &
```

This works, if I activate it manually through ssh.  But I want it to run on bootup, so I added that line to my /etc/rc.local and now it won't run.  It runs without the "-u", but then it won't write output.
Am I stuck with using some sort of logging module?
Thanks

Comment: Logging always better, can use any tail command for back-trace  ! Run bash and call python script .

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/). Pretty sure it's exactly what you're looking for.

Here's a great tutorial for it too: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-manage-supervisor-on-ubuntu-and-debian-vps

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is almost exactly what I want.  However, my python script uses a module that requires the script to be run with a "sudo" in front.  I can't seem to get Supervisor to run my script as root... Any ideas?  I wish I could just remove the permissions on that module, but I've tried, and I cant find the dang thing anywhere.

Comment: It turns out that there was a problem with the supervisor.conf file on my install.  Using their github issues, I was able to remedy the problem.  Supervisor works great!  Although I can't get the stdout to actually work.  The err file is the one that's important, so thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would add as a cronjob. Use

```
sudo contab -e
```

and add

```
@reboot /path/to/pythonscript
```

Also make sure the python file was made executable with

```
chmod +x myfile.py
```